# Givens : $f(x)=x^2$ , $F_1 (x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, $F_2(x)=F_1(x)+4$. Question : express $F_2$ with the form $ F_2=\int_b^x f(t)dt$, i.e. find $b$.

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Givens : $f(x)=x^2$ , $F_1 (x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, $F_2(x)=F_1(x)+4$. Question : express $F_2$ with the form $ F_2=\int_b^x f(t)dt$, i.e. find $b$.

For a better undersanding of this example : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wmr887ecoh

---

The title of my question may not be as clear as desirable.

Here is what I mean.

***Givens of the problem :***

$(1)$ Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function, let's say on $\mathbb R$.

$(2)$ Suppose that both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are primitives of $f$, and that $F_2(x) = F_1(x)+C $ with $C\neq 0$ and $C$ known to us.

$(3)$ Suppose also that both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are integrals of $f$.

Note : I add this hypothesis explicitly since not all primitives of a function are also integrals of this function, if, as it seems to me, the converse of the FTC is not true.

$(4)$ Suppose that we know the lower limit of integration of $F_1$ , I mean, we know the value of $a$ in the true statement

$$ F_1 = \int _a ^x f(t)dt.$$

( I claim the statement is true for some $a$, since  , by hypothesis, $F_1$ is an integral of $f$).

(5) Since $F_2$( by hypothesis) is also an integral of $f$, it must be true for some $b \space ( \neq a)$ that :

$$ F_2 = \int_b^x f(t)dt.$$

***My question*** ( in case the situation I've described actually makes sense) is :

> assuming we know the value of $C$  (with $C = F_2(x)-F_1(x)) $) , and the value of $a$ as said above  , is it possible
> to determine the value of $b$?

Or, in short :

> how to relate the way $F_1$ and $F_2$ differ as primitives , and the
> way they differ as integrals ( the first difference being a matter of
> " constant $C$" and the second difference being a matter of lower
> limit of integration).

Comment: If $F_1$ is periodic, say $f(x) = cos(x)$, $F_1(x) = \sin(x)$, and $F_2(x) = \sin(x) + 1/2$, then there are infinitely many choices of $b$: $b \in \{2\pi k - \pi/6 : k \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the difference:$$F_2(x)-F_1(x)=\int_b^xf(x)dx-\int_0^xf(x)dx$$
you can use $$\int_\alpha^\beta f(x)dx=-\int_\beta^\alpha f(x) dx$$
Then $$F_2(x)-F_1(x)=\int_b^0f(x)dx$$
You can then just plug in $f(x)$ to calculate $b$.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I find  $b= - (12^{1/3})$.